# Ubuntu 20.04 - 4K screen doesn't work on 60 fps [Works fine in 2K@60fps or in windows at 4K@60fps]

Tags: drivers, graphics, display-resolution, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I use a Lenovo Thinkpad with AMD® Ryzen 7 2700u with radeon vega mobile gfx with Samsung 4K UHD TV.

Laptop has support for 4K@60fps and it works perfectly fine on Windows but not on Ubuntu. On Ubuntu 4k@30fps or 2k@60fps works fine but not 4K@60fps.

If it helps, my linux kernel is: 5.4

Any leads will be highly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! There are two things I did:

1. From the Ubuntu Login screen, choose "Ubuntu Wayland" as your primary display and then login.
2. I have a Samsung TU8079 (8000 series) 4K TV. From the settings, I disabled the "Input Signal Plus" option for my HDMI input and then i was able to see 4k@60HZ as an option for my display.

Resolved the issue fully! hope this helps someone.